DevOPs Center: AppSwitcher of Type AppMenu failed to deploy due to In field: AppMenuItem.Name - no ConnectedApp named Chatter_Desktop
This is a Dev Ops Centre question.
I'm trying to deploy a bundle to Production from my final staging environment, which is a partial sandbox.
It deployed to the partial with no issues, but fails to Production with this issue:
AppSwitcher of Type AppMenu failed to deploy due to In field: AppMenuItem.Name - no ConnectedApp named Chatter_Desktop found
I can see what it's referring to in my AppSwitcher.appMenu-meta.xml
<appMenuItems>
    <name>Chatter_Desktop</name>
    <type>ConnectedApp</type>
</appMenuItems>

And I can see Chatter Desktop chilling out in my Connected Apps in production.
This bundle includes a new unrelated lightning app (first new one since starting using DevOpsCentre) so that's brought AppMenus into my project metadata when it wasn't before.
Is this a known issue?
Is the answer to find way to change the Chatter Desktop connected app so the AppMenu can find it, or to just delete it's appMenuItem from AppSwitcher.appMenu-meta.xml. will this cause issues?
I've just noticed that AppMenu in Setup is a blank page in production, so now I'm wondering if it's a version issue.
Thanks!
Elliot
